# Strange CSS background Image Resizing

Tags: wordpress, css, background, background-image

I have a custom background image on one of my Wordpress login pages. After upgrading to the latest version this background image is now squished down and looks terrible.

I can't find any issues in the CSS - maybe there is some type of background-width or background-height property? But if anybody can figure it out that would be so incredible!

Here's the link to the login page: http://www.destinyislands.com/wp-login.php

Comment: The body tag has a class 'login' that's inheriting the 274 63, can you remove the login class on the body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there's a new css file in wp-admin/css/wp-admin.css.

The .login h1 a element is assigned a background-size of 274px 63px.  Get rid of that line and it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have a background-size attribute of "background-size: 274px 63px;"  If you remove that, you can fix that image.

Or Add this to override the wp-admin.css

```
background-size: 330px 128px;
```